# TypeError: data.forEach is not a function in react while fetching data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

i am getting TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
i am trying to fetch data from API
for my dashboard, but working for the url i studied in tutorial
i am using react table
axios

```
function App() {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    
    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const result = await axios("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1");
        setData(result.data);
      })();
    }, []);

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        
        Header: "User",
        
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "ID",
            accessor: "data.id"
          },
          {
            Header: "Email",
            accessor: "data.email"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

your data object is inside `result.data.data`.

```js
function App() {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    
    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const result = await axios("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1");
         //  result.data is from axios response (it have all data from api)
         // your data object is inside result.data.data
        setData(result.data.data);
      })();
    }, []);

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        
        Header: "User",
        
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "ID",
            accessor: "data.id"
          },
          {
            Header: "Email",
            accessor: "data.email"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: @Chaitanya  please accept and upvote my answer if it solves your problem. Thanks